# Sizing an existing svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to learn how to deal with an existing svg properly so that I can align it with text.

This is how I (probably naively) understand things so far:

`viewport` - the area of the canvas that I can see on my screen, set by the width/height attributes in the svg tag or css.

`viewBox` - defines panning and scale within that viewport.

Usually it seems that your svg height/width should match your viewBox, but the following [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOXpgM) makes me think that the size of the vector itself (or path i guess) matters. I've no problem manipulating the circle because I set its size.

Do I just have to finely tune the viewBox of the icon until it is centered and the correct size? Or is there a better way I don't know about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very sure I understand your question. Maybe this helps: In JavaScript there is a method `getBBox()`that returns the size and position of a rectangle circumscribing the current element.
In your example if I'm putting this in the JavaScript:

```js
let thepath = document.querySelector("path");
console.log(thepath.getBBox());
```

I get `SVGRect {x: 0, y: 1, width: 15, height: 15}`. This is the size and the position of the icon.
You can center the icon by changing the `viewBox="-42.5 -42 100 100"`or by translating the icon using CSS: `path{transform:translate(42.5px,42px)`

Comment: I'd use `document.querySelector('svg.icon')` to get the content of the whole icon.

Comment: interesting - yes, thanks, you have. that JS has provided the answer: although I centered it by using the result of your query `viewBox="0 1 15 15"` :)

Comment: @enxaneta Good helpful answer for me!